# Mosaic of rasters is big, black rectangle in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, mosaic

I am brand new to QGIS and the world of maps. I have four GeoTiffs inside QGIS. I can merge them just fine using the Merge command, but when I try to use the Mosaic command instead I just end up with a black screen and a new layer which has a Min value of NaN and a really low Max number.

Can anyone tell me why and how to fix that, please? I see someone else had a similar problem in ArcGIS:
[Why is mosaic of rasters big, black rectangle in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23566/why-is-my-mosaic-of-rasters-a-big-black-rectangle)

I've since followed [this guide](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/151248/94167) for calculating statistics and then re-run Mosaic but nothing changed, it's still just blackness.

(The reason I'm using Mosaic and not Merge is because in a bit I'm going to need this command with a 5th image that overlays the other 4, and this is just a simple test.)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  You mention that answers in another Q&A didn't help - what did you try and was there any change or no difference at all?  Have you tried anything else?  Please [edit] your question to add any extra info.

Comment: Did you try recalculating your statistics?  It seemed to work in the other Q&A for ArcGIS Desktop.

Comment: I didn't because I don't know what that means, and thought perhaps it was something specific to ArcGIS. I've since followed this guide and then re-run Mosaic and nothing changed, it's still just blackness http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/151248/94167

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 3):

TO merge raster layer, you can use the `Merge raster layers` tool. You can get the tool from `Processing Toolbox -> GDAL/OGR -> Miscellaneous -> Merge raster layers`.

But before the mosaic process, you need to confirm the data type of the raster images. You can check the raster data type from `Layer properties` -> `Metadata`, then go to Data Type. In the example below the data type is 16 bit signed integer. Thus, the output data type should be the same.

[image]

Here is an example of of SRTM data before mosaic:

[image]

1. Open the merge tool from `Processing Toolbox -> GDAL/OGR ->
   Miscellaneous -> Merge raster layers`
2. Select the raster images using the `...` dots
3. Select `Int16` (in my case), yours might be different depending on the input data type
4. Define the output file name with extension such as tif for example.

[image]

Here is the output mosaic DEM

[image]

Comment: The user does not want the 'Merge' function, they want the 'Mocaic' function